# React function will not rerender even if state hook called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

In this function:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomeScreen from  './Screens/HomeScreen'
import './App.css';
import currentStrings from './utils/currentlang'

function App() {

  const [currentlang, setCurrentStrings] = React.useState(currentStrings)
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
       <div className="grid-container">
        <header className="header">
          <div className="brand">
            <Link to="/" >
                
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="header-side">
            {currentlang.getCurrent.subtitle}
          </div>
          <div className="header-right">
            <button  onClick={() => setCurrentStrings(currentlang.switchLang())}> {currentlang.getCurrent.traduction} </button>
          </div>
          <div>

          </div>
        </header>
        <main className="main">
          <div className="content">
            <Route path="/" exact={true} component={HomeScreen} />
          </div>

        </main>
        <footer className="footer">
          &#169; 2020 
         </footer>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

I use a button (`<button  onClick={() => setCurrentStrings(currentlang.switchLang())}>` ) to change one of the properties of the object currentStrings (or currentLang used for the useState hook)

However it seems my function does not rerender, i can confirm this since my logs do tell the object does change its properties when the button is clicked, but the screen does not show it.

```
import {strings as frstrings} from '../res/lang/fr/strings'
import {strings as engstrings} from '../res/lang/eng/strings'

class CurentLang {
    constructor(){
        this.current = engstrings;    
    }
    switchLang() {
        if(this.current === frstrings){
            this.current = engstrings;
            console.log("engstrings");
        } else{
            this.current = frstrings;
            console.log("frstrings");
        }
        return new this.CurentLang;
    }
    get getCurrent(){
        return this.current;
    }

}

var currentStrings = new CurentLang()

export default currentStrings;
```

Comment: Maybe it is because the reference to the property did not change. `currentlang.switchLang()` has to create a completely new object so the reference to the property changes.

Comment: the code seems weird. what does `currentStrings ` look like?

Comment: @bubulledu93 , why i have to create a new instance? is there a way to force a rerender in that case?

Comment: can you add it to your post please and delete from the comment

Comment: you are setting the value of currentStrings to the return of switchLang function. instead, you want to update that object, and then the state should figure out what the new language is.

Comment: what do you mean by that? instead of calling the function i should call the function and then return the object on the onClick event?

Comment: Your `CurrentLang` class is acting as a custom react hook but is interacting badly with `useState` the docs cover custom functional hooks here: [Building your own hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

Comment: Are you not getting an error? `this.CurentLang` is not a constructor.